# Box Oauth Powershell authorization

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, box

Maybe I am stupid or something.

But I have not been able to make the Box API work for me.

I cannot even get the authorization code and the refresh token etc.

I had wanted to write an automated powershell script that would upload to box twice a day from my server, without requiring the user being signed in for box sync.

I cant use the developer token all the time since it only works manually for 60 mins, and cannot be refreshed.

I try to follow the instructions and try to get the url with the id and token data etc that you are supposed to get after hitting "GRANT ACCESS" to the app. but that takes me directly to my folders.

What can I do here?

Comment: Sounds like something you should [contact Box about](https://community.box.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/BoxSearchLithiumTKB)

Comment: I might not be doing something wrong?

Comment: I've not used it but you could use a module already created elsewhere. https://github.com/mbegan/Box-PSModule

Comment: I have the same issue where I am lead to Grant access in the browser ... then .. nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my issue

I had to make sure the redirect uri was `https:\\localhost` and then copy the authorization code from there and proceed to use the API without the developer token